# generate columns based on row dates

Tags: r, date, dplyr, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

I need to create a column based on dates, this is my dataset:

```
test <- data.frame(PatientID = c("1000285","1000317", "1000399","10006485","10995700317" ), dateMI = c(NA, NA, "2008-10-26", "2008-10-26", NA),dateA = c(NA, NA,"2008-10-26", "2010-11-06", "2019-02-14"), dateCVA = c("2014-02-04", "2001-02-27", NA, NA, "2020-02-14"),  stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I would need to create an extra column called `dateEVENT`, that contains the most recent date from `dateMI`, `dateA` and `dateCVA`.

So effectively the new dataset would look like the one below:

```
test <- data.frame(PatientID = c("1000285","1000317", "1000399","10006485","10995700317" ), dateMI = c(NA, NA, "2008-10-26", "2008-10-26", NA),dateA = c(NA, NA,"2008-10-26", "2010-11-06", "2019-02-14"), dateCVA = c("2014-02-04", "2001-02-27", NA, NA, "2020-02-14"), dateEVENT = c("2014-02-04", "2001-02-27", "2008-10-26", "2010-11-06", "2020-02-14"),  stringsAsFactors = F)
```

What would be the best way of doing this?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to loop over the rows with `rowwise` and get the `max` 'date' after converting the date columns to `Date` class

```
library(dplyr)
test1 <- test %>% 
      mutate(across(starts_with('date'), as.Date)) %>%
      rowwise %>% 
      mutate(dateEVENT = max(c_across(starts_with('date')), 
        na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
      ungroup
```

-output

```
test1
# A tibble: 5 x 5
#  PatientID   dateMI     dateA      dateCVA    dateEVENT 
#  <chr>       <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>    
#1 1000285     NA         NA         2014-02-04 2014-02-04
#2 1000317     NA         NA         2001-02-27 2001-02-27
#3 1000399     2008-10-26 2008-10-26 NA         2008-10-26
#4 10006485    2008-10-26 2010-11-06 NA         2010-11-06
#5 10995700317 NA         2019-02-14 2020-02-14 2020-02-14
```